# New user registration fields

Tags: 7, users

I have a site with about 30 members, but I just added a new mandatory field on the registration. I want the old members to be forced to fill this in as well. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you have developing knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one:

1. Use the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to test whether the user has authenticated and the field value of the current user is empty. Redirect to `user/[uid]/edit` if this is the case.
2. Do the same test in a module during your implementation of [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7). Call

   ```
   drupal_goto('user/[uid]/edit')
   ```

   to redirect to the user edit page.
3. Do the same test in a module during your implementation of [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7). Call

   ```
   menu_set_active_item('user/[uid]/edit');
   ```

   to show the user edit page.

Replace `[uid]` by the user id of the currently logged in user.

In cases 1 and 2, you also have to make sure that you do not redirect from `'user/[uid]/edit'` back to `'user/[uid]/edit'`. This would create an infinite  loop of redirections, because the POST data gets lost when redirecting.

Documentation:

- [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)
- [menu_set_active_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_item/7)

Comment: I couldn't make a rule that would take them to the edit page, but I made a rule that takes them to their account and gives a message to "edit account". Good enough for me. Everytime I tried to make it go to "user/[account:id]/edit" it would give me an access denied error. Weird.